Endpoint with double backslashes resulting in failure of exporting results to JIRA using mikepenz/xray-action@v3.0.4
I am using mikepenz/xray-action@v3.0.4 to import junit xml results to JIRA. It was working well earlier this year and suddenly started failing with below error in github:
Error:  Failed to import: /__w/repo_name/repo_name/project_name/target/surefire-reports/junitreports/TEST-com.project.quality.project_name.test.cucumber.options.TestRunner.xml ({"name":"HTTPError","code":"ERR_NON_2XX_3XX_RESPONSE","timings":{"start":1713549674111,"socket":1713549674112,"lookup":1713549674112,"connect":1713549674112,"secureConnect":1713549674112,"upload":1713549674112,"response":1713549710288,"end":1713549710289,"phases":{"wait":1,"dns":0,"tcp":0,"tls":0,"request":0,"firstByte":36176,"download":1,"total":36178}}})
After debugging it further, I can see the endpoint in debug logs -
##[debug]Using endpoint: https://xray.cloud.getxray.app//api/v2/import/execution/junit
Due to extra slash before the 'api', it's failing. Tried with different formats, these endpoints comes with 2 slashes.
Can someone please help in getting this resolved. As it look like this is an in-built endpoint added to mikepenz xray-action, and we don't have an access to it directly?
XRAY action call in workflow file:

name: "Import Regression Test results to Xray"
if: always()
uses: mikepenz/xray-action@v3.0.4
with:
username: ${{ secrets.XRAY_CLIENT_ID }}
password: ${{ secrets.XRAY_CLIENT_SECRET }}
testFormat: "junit"
testPaths: "project_name/target/surefire-reports/junitreports/TEST-com.project.quality.project_name.test.cucumber.options.TestRunner.xml"
projectKey: "PROJECT_KEY"
testExecKey: ${{ github.event.inputs.jiraRegressionTestExecKey }}
failOnImportError: false


I was going to recommend to report that as a issue on the xray-action GitHub project but I see that you just did that.
As Xray cloud endpoints are non-customizable, that needs to be addressed on the code.
It would help the xray-action GH team if you could identify the version that worked well before in your case, to understand exactly when that regression (assuming it exists) was introduced.
Right now, the only workaround would be to use a previous version of xray-action.
